# React unable to find component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a React App.. largely my attempts so far are based on the default application from `create-react-app`. Here's my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './Components/MyComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponent/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

MyComponent is defined here:

```
import React from 'react';
import img from './Assets/img.png';
import imgComponent from './MyImage';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return
        <div>
            <imgComponent imageProp={img} />

        </div>
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 8:  'MyComponent' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
```

Please could someone tell me why I'm getting this error? I was under the impression that a combination of the `import` in App.js and the `export default` in `MyComponent` was all that was needed to use the component.

Comment: `import MyComponent from  './Components/MyComponent';`

Comment: replace `import './Components/MyComponent';` with `import MyComponent from './Components/MyComponent';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the App.js you added `MyComponent` to the render method, but `MyComponent` is not defined in your code (as the error message says).

Just change your third import:

`import './Components/MyComponent';`

To:

`import MyComponent from './Components/MyComponent';`

So you got the component you are using in your render function.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When we are doing `export default Mycomponent`, we are exposing the Mycomponent module to other modules. But we require a local name to access the contents. For a default export, it doesn't have to be the same as export. A simple import statement should look like `import name from 'module'`.
In your case, it will be

`import MyComponent from './Components/MyComponent'`.